# How to make a button that when clicked will drop down more information in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I apologize if this is a duplicate as I can't seem to come up with the right name for what I aim to achieve - I would like to make a button (looks like a downward facing arrow) that would be next to a Label or something and when the user clicks the arrow it would drop down more information about the contents of the label. This would hopefully be achieved within Tkinter, but if this is not an option I can explore other libraries as well.

[image: When button has not been clicked]

Here I include a picture example of what I want to achieve:

[image: After the button is clicked]

Please note that what I am trying to achieve is not the same as a drop-down selection menu.

Also, I am new to stack overflow, so feel free to leave any criticism on how I could ask my question better!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the ttk.TreeView widget to solve this problem?

Comment: I will definitely try this! @BryanOakley

Comment: Forgot to update; This was a perfect solution! Thank you! @BryanOakley